# Out of memory using adapters

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-context

I'm getting Out of memory errors. I checked the DDMS and find that the places I allocate more memory is in the getView() method in my adapters. Is it a better way for me to create objects then this way:

```
view=new ImageView(myContext);
```

This is one example of my getView() method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView==null){
        view=new ImageView(myContext);
        view.setLayoutParams( new AbsListView.LayoutParams(columnWidth,columnWidth));
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }else{
        view=convertView;
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
    return view;
}
```

I get the context in the c'tor:

```
public emptySquaresAdapter( Context myContext,) {
    super();
    this.myContext=myContext;
}
```

I read about context leak, is that the case?

EDIT:

In this case I show all the views in the screen at once, so the converted view is never used (I don't need to scroll to show more views).

this adapter shows 12 squares on the screen. The method getView is called 12 times with the position 0 (I guess to measure all the child vies) and only then continues to position 1,2,3...
Why doe's it happens? Can this make the OOM problem?
I call this adapter from another adapter, and I guess that what makes everything complicated.

I also unbind all drawables at onDestroy, and set imageView.getDrawable().setCallback(null) to all of the imageViewsIt still doesn't work

Comment: You're more likely not removing ImageViews when they're no longer needed so they just keep stacking.

Comment: put in some logs to see if the convertView is working properly.

Comment: Impossible to know with the code you posted. Please post the minimum code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You used plural (adapters)... How many adapters are we talking about? Could you explain a bit more about how the UI is populated?

Comment: I edited my question. Can you please look again? The rest of the code is pretty long, so I don't know what exactly to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is ok. The problem is, probably, somewhere else.

P.S. Why do you store context object? You can get it any time you need in your getView() method by calling parent.getContext()

And to my experience, it doesn't matter what kind of context you pass as long as you don't hold onto that (what you are actually doing).

But if your adapter itself is not stored somewhere and is just a part of an activity it should be ok, since adapter will just get gc'ed with activity.

Comment: Thanks, I defiantly going to use parent.getContext()!

Comment: The problem was that I was using the Gallery widget (small detail :-) which doesn't recycle it's views. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that you pass the `Application` context (`getApplicationContext()`)not the Activity context (`this` for e.g.), since using `Activity` context can cause memory leaks as the objects they are bound to (`view` in your implementaion) will not be Garbage Collected causing a memory leak and  OutOfMemory exception.

Another thing you should avoid is creating a new `View` each time you `getView()` is called. `convertView` is a recycled view (the view that is poped out when you scroll) that will be used as the new `View` for the row that appears after scroll. Use it instead of creating `view` object every call (it will not cause Outofmemory exception if GC collects it but may cause slow scrolling when GC runs).

Comment: can I call getApplicationContext() from the adapter without context? I agree about the converted view but in this case, all the view's are presented in the screen at once and there is no need to scroll

Comment: It is what you pass to the constructor that I am concerned about. If you create your adapter with `emptySquaresAdapter(getApplicationContext())` and not `emptySquaresAdapter(this)`, you should not have the memory leak I am talking about. `getView()` is called for each row, so you are creating an `ImageView` for each row you have, which, if you have a leak due to Activity context, will not be GC

Answer (score 0):

you never assign the `convertView` in the first instance. So, every time the `getView()` is called you create a new `ImageView`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView==null){
        convertView=new ImageView(myContext);
        convertView.setLayoutParams( new AbsListView.LayoutParams(columnWidth,columnWidth));
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }else{

        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```